# Maven Application fails to connect to database server

Tags: java, mysql, mamp

I am developing a Maven project using Netbeans platform. My application request a database and i used MAMP tool to create a mySQL database. Now that everything is developed, i need to create the executable jar file in which i can run it on other computers. When i launched the .jar file from my computer is works perfectly but when i launching it from another computer it seems that there is no interactivity between my database server. Can anyone help me to solve my problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you are able to access `mysql` database from your development machine but not from other machine. For accessing `mysql` database from other machines also, you need to grant remote access of `mysql` database to your different machine.

For this, execute following queries on `mysql` server as `root` user for creating a new user and granting remote access to that user -

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment below line in  /etc/mysql/my.cnf file, if it is there -

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

And restart mysql server -

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Through these queries, you are allowing access of database of this user from any IP address, means from any machine you can access your database.